# Embedding a YouTube channel

Tags: 7, files, nodes

Recently i did small project for a community now their requirement is to include a block that contain a YouTube video frame and they have to display their YouTube channel there, So i have installed emfield module but i don't know how to implement that. Is there any suggestion like which module is comfort for these purpose ? and How to use emfield ?

Comment: emfield docs here http://drupal.org/node/184346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, every YT-channel has it's own embed code. Try to embed this code to your block and make sure "Full HTML" is set as text-format.

Look here as well: [Embed You-Tube channel](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=4c414f514bc3f690&hl=en)

Comment: Refer this link https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en